# bind9 doesn't load zone with only CNAME record

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to set up a subdomain to point to Google Sites, so I made a simple zone file:

```
$ttl 38400
subdomain.mydomain.net.    IN CNAME ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

This doesn't work:

```
zone subdomain.mydomain.net/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone subdomain.mydomain.net/IN: has no NS records
zone subdomain.mydomain.net/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

But adding an NS or SOA record gives a "CNAME and other data" error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you bother with a zone file? Do you already use bind? Why didn't you just put this CNAME record in the domain's zone?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I had always used separate zone files for subdomains before and it worked, but those were pointed to the same server using its IP address.

I tried adding the CNAME entry to the zone file for mydomain.net instead of creating a separate file, but I get the same error.

Comment: You made a separate zone file for every DNS record?!?

Comment: For every domain/subdomain. What should I have done instead?

Comment: Put them all in your zone file, as normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a `CNAME` at apex of your domain name, per design of the DNS.

And you can't have a valid zone without `SOA` and `NS` records which is exactly why you can't have a `CNAME` record at apex, since `CNAME` is incompatible, besides DNSSEC related records, with any other records on the same name, for obvious reasons of ambiguity otherwise.

Comment: I got it working by adding the subdomain to the zone file for mydomain.net rather than creating a new file.

Answer (score 0):

You should only create subdomains if you want to transfer authority for that subdomain to a different team/entity. If you manage all those subdomains yourself, there isn't really a good reason for creating different subdomains.

Below you can see an example configuration file for a zone ([source](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-bind-zone-examples.html))

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
$TTL 86400
@       SOA    dns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
               2001062501 ; serial
               21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
               3600       ; retry after 1 hour
               604800     ; expire after 1 week
               86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day
;
;
        NS     dns1.example.com.
        NS     dns2.example.com.
dns1    A      10.0.1.1
        AAAA   aaaa:bbbb::1
dns2    A      10.0.1.2
        AAAA   aaaa:bbbb::2
;
;
@       MX     10 mail.example.com.
        MX     20 mail2.example.com.
mail    A      10.0.1.5
        AAAA   aaaa:bbbb::5
mail2   A      10.0.1.6
        AAAA   aaaa:bbbb::6
;
;
; This sample zone file illustrates sharing the same IP addresses for
; multiple services:
;
services  A      10.0.1.10
          AAAA   aaaa:bbbb::10
          A      10.0.1.11
          AAAA   aaaa:bbbb::11

ftp       CNAME  services.example.com.
www       CNAME  services.example.com.
;
; The items below I have added myself.
;
subdomain                    CNAME  ghs.googlehosted.com.
mailserver.other-subdomain   A      192.0.2.25
webserver.other-subdomain    A      203.0.113.80
cname.other-subdomain        CNAME  webserver.other-subdomain.example.com.
```

As you can see from the example, you do not have to create a separate zone for "other-subdomain" or for "subdomain". You can add all those records to the master zone file for the domain.